# a banana and an apple is correct

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I have to make slide where I have to write database and application word, so I want to know which sentence is correct?

> There is a database and an application.

or

> There is a database and application.

Actually I want to know **and** conjunction rule in english language when consonant and vowel word is together in a sentence.

Ps. I do not want to change the order of the word in this particular sentence.

Comment: please explain the reason for downvoting the post.it will be helpful for me

Comment: I upvoted to counter downvote. I also answered your question the best I could. However, it's not entirely clear what it is you're asking. It could be that you're thinking of something else, but there are not particular rules for "and" with respect to consonant and vowel words in the same sentences, but there are rules to indefinite articles "a" and "an" and how you'd use them in a sentence that might affect how you use them when using the conjunction "and". Please see my answer below.

Comment: Usage of *and* doesn't depend on whether words start with consonants or vowels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is **a** database and **an** application.

This sentence is correct. This is explicitly separating or enumerating parts.

> There is **a** database and application.

This sentence is **also** correct. This is implicitly suggesting that these two parts are parts of one whole.

> There is a database and **a** application.

This sentence is incorrect. "A" application is not grammatically correct; for nouns beginning with a vowel, use the indefinite article "an" instead.

> There is **an** database and an application.

This sentence is incorrect. "An" database is not grammatically correct; for nouns beginning with a consonant, use the indefinite article "a" instead.

***An aside:***

> There **is** **a** databases and **an** applications.

This sentence is incorrect. For plurals, you do not use indefinite articles. In addition, the verb **is** must be pluralized as well to **are**.

> There are databases and applications.

This sentence is correct.

Comment: any reference for the aside note will be more helpful for me.

Comment: any reference for the aside note will be more helpful for me. first you saying this is correct and later you said contradiction.

Comment: @diEcho not sure what you mean by contradiction. "There is a database and an application." is correct and "There is a databases and an applications." is incorrect. The reason is provided below. Plurals do not use indefinite articles. The verb must also be pluralized (meaning, "is" -> "are"). This isn't a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

"No, I have a bother and sister" is grammatically acceptable as is "No, I have a brother and a sister." Those two sentences, however, have slightly different nuances in meaning.

The first example focuses on the two people as members of a single collection, namely the speaker's siblings. It denotes that the set of the speaker's siblings differ with respect to sex while subtly implying that the similarity of siblinghood outweighs the difference in sex. It would be a perfectly grammatical answer to the question of "Is it true that you have three siblings," a question in which sex is not of importance.

The second example focuses on the two people being similar in one respect but differing in another relevant respect. It would be a perfectly grammatical answer to "Is it true that you have two brothers," a question that implies sex is a relevant consideration.

Notice that I constructed these examples so that both nouns started with a consonant. The choice of whether one or multiple indefinite articles are needed does not depend on whether the nouns' initial phonemes are in the same or different classes. It depends on whether what is being stressed is similarity or difference.

EDIT:

In response to the comment by the OP, I think you misunderstood my answer.

Of course it is true that an indefinite article is either "a" or "an" depending on whether the initial letter of the immediately succeeding word is a consonant or a vowel.

But that rule applies to WHICH indefinite article to use, not how many.

HOW MANY indefinite articles to use depends on what you want to stress. In your example, if you want to stress that the service being discussed combines the power of an application and a data base, then just ONE article implies that, and the article to be used will depend on the immediately succeeding word. If what you want to stress is that one service provides two kinds of benefit, then use TWO articles.

Comment: Thank you for valuable information but I am.afraid to say that this is not what I am asking for. it is not a case of singular or  plural things but the vowel and consonant starting words when using *and*

Comment: My examples each used the singular "brother" and "sister." You are missing my point, which went directly to your question. What controls WHICH indefinite article to use does depend on whether the immediately following word (not the relevant noun) begins with a consonant or vowel. We say " a red apple" rather than "an red apple." What controls HOW MANY definite articles to use depends on what you want to emphasize among two lined things.

Comment: Please disregard the above comment. Part of it got dropped. Instead see edit to my answer.

Comment: Just highlighting a humorous typo in the first sentence of your answer. To some, *bothers* and *brothers* have more than just nuanced differences, quite apart from the issue of articles. Others may disagree. :P

Comment: @Lawrence "To some, bothers and brothers have more than just nuanced differences" is only true in some cases. Very nice!

Answer (score -3):

The first option is correct:

"There is a database and an application."

As you correctly point out the rule is dependent on the presence of either a consonant or a vowel at the start of the following word.

Even if the following word begins with a vowel, the indefinite article still has to be an.

The only time this is removed is if the next word refers to a plural.

So for examplein your case if there were multiple applications then you would correctly say:

There is a database and applications.

Check out [this page for reference.](https://www.englishpage.com/articles/a-vs-an.htm)

Comment: Both options are perfectly correct. You'd probably only say *There is a database and application* if the database and the application were closely linked, but this may be the case in the OP's presentation.

Comment: I disagree. Whilst I accept that the second option is used widely (and in my opinion incorrectly), it is not grammatically correct and I know that the OP would rather be advised as to what is the correct way however popular the incorrect alternatives may be. The OP wants to know which is correct and also the conjunction rule, both of which I answered.

Comment: there is no multiple database or application . only one database and one application ,  yes both are closely linked.

Comment: In that case...

The first option is correct:

"There is a database and an application."

Comment: People don't actually follow your "rule" when they write or speak. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+mother+and+infant%2C+a+mother+and+an+infant+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20mother%20and%20infant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20mother%20and%20an%20infant%3B%2Cc0). (The Ngram shows that *a mother and infant* is more common than *a mother and an infant*.)

Comment: Hmm, like I say popularity ≠ correct

Comment: @PaulaLivingstone I respectfully disagree. There are different connotations for stating "There is an X and a Y" and "There is an X and Y" in the grouping "There is (an X) and (a Y)" and "There is (an X and Y)" that you're completely overlooking.

Comment: Can you at least provide some evidence that anybody else thinks that *"a mother and infant"* is grammatically incorrect?